# hide/show multiple elements if each of them is visible

Tags: jquery

```
if ($('#menutx').is(':visible')){ 
    $('#menutx').addClass('tohide');
}

$('.tohide').hide();
//some code...
$('.tohide').show();
```

So, `if visible`, I hide some elements while some code is executing.
How can I do this for multiple elements ?
Other elements are `#panelb, #menut, #slidet, .linegold, #btnlines, #footerwrap, #alert.`

Comment: Your question seems to unclear, can you re-elaborate

Comment: do you want to do this in any  event like button click or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the elements in an array and loop through them:

```
var list=['#panelb', '#menut', '#slidet', '.linegold', '#btnlines', '#footerwrap', '#alert'];

$.each(list,function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
      $(this).removeClass('toshow').addClass('tohide'); // Be sure to remove `toshow` class
    }      
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is what you exactly want. initially some elements are hidden and some are showing. accroding to the visiblity, it check and show hidden ones and hide showing one. refer the example with demo.good luck.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: monospace;
}

</style>

<body>

<ul class="mymenu">
 <li><a href="" id="id0">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id1">HOME1111</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id2">HOME2222</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id3" style="display:none">HOME3333</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id4">HOME4444</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id5">HOME9999</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id6" style="display:none">HOME8888</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id7" style="display:none">HOME7777</a></li>
 <li><a href="" id="id8">HOME6666</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="show">Show Hidden</button> || <button id="hide">Hide Showing</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#show").click(function(){
 var thelength = $("ul.mymenu").children().length;
 for(var i=0;i<thelength;i++)
 {
  var checkvisible = $("ul.mymenu li #id"+i).is(':visible');
  if (checkvisible == true) 
   {
    $("ul.mymenu li #id"+i).hide(500);
   }
  else
  {
   $("ul.mymenu li #id"+i).show(1000);

  }
 }
 
});


$("#hide").click(function(){
 var thelength = $("ul.mymenu").children().length;
 for(var i=0;i<thelength;i++)
 {
  var checkvisible = $("ul.mymenu li #id"+i).is(':visible');
  if (checkvisible == true) 
   {
    $("ul.mymenu li #id"+i).hide(500);
   }
  else
  {
   $("ul.mymenu li #id"+i).show(1000);

  }
 }
 
});


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menutx,#panelb, #menut, #slidet, .linegold, #btnlines, #footerwrap, #alert").each(function(){

        if ($(this).is(':visible'))

            $(this).addClass('tohide');

    })
})
```

You can remove `addClass` and use of `hide` and `show` only.

Example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        #menutx,#panelb {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
        }
        #panelb {
            left: 200px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        
        <ul id="menutx">
             <li>menutx-Item1</li>
             <li>menutx-Item2</li>
             <li>menutx-Item3</li>
             <li>menutx-Item4</li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul id="panelb">
            <li>panelb-item1</li>
            <li>panelb-item2</li>
            <li>panelb-item3</li>
        </ul>

        <button>Click Me!</button>

       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
        <script>
          
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("button").on("click",function(){
        
        $("#menutx,#panelb, #menut, #slidet, .linegold, #btnlines, #footerwrap, #alert").each(function(){
        
        if ($(this).is(':visible'))
            
            $(this).hide(500);
            
        else
            
            $(this).show(500);
            
        })
        
    })
})
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this will show elements which were not visible at start !